# Mount multiple NFS subdirs with differents options

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

The following setup:

```
ip_address:/maindir/subdir001 /mnt/test001 nfs soft,nfsvers=3,timeo=50,retrans=2 0 2
ip_address:/maindir/subdir002 /mnt/test002 nfs soft 0 2
ip_address:/maindir/subdir003 /mnt/test003 nfs hard 0 2
```

Mounting these directories, I would expect the output of `mount` to show each got their own options. Instead, all 3 get the options of the first one mounted.

How can I change this? Preferably without editing the export options on the NFS server.

Comment: This may answer your problem: https://superuser.com/a/894907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that that you mount the server several times, the NFS internally created only once (once per server). Thus, only option of the first mount are used.

If you really need different options, thes you should assign multiple IP addresses to the server. This, however, will work only with nfs v3, as v4 has on protocol level server equality detection.

Comment: Looks like this, and the comment about subtree checking are how it is. So really an issue on the NFS server itself.